# Is it useful to Explicitly close SqlConnection just before exiting method

Tags: sql

I have 100s of such methods and each method is called more than thousand times.
Here with each call a new SqlConnection is  created)(taken from pool). Though the methods are small and control immediately leaves the method and SqlConnection is supposed to be collected by GC.

```
Method()
 { 
   MyComponent adapter = new MyComponent (); 
   adapter.Connection = GetConnection(dbContext);//Here I get new SqlConnection 
   adapter.Update(_SqlTable);
```

} //End of Method

**My question is** - Does the following optimization makes any difference ??

```
Method(){
        MyComponent adapter = new MyComponent ();
        adapter.Connection = GetConnection(dbContext);//Here I get new SqlConnection
        adapter.Update(_SqlTable);
        adapter.Connection.Close() // Or Dispose()
   } //End of Method
```

Is there any better way to write these methods (e.g make them static static methods )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should absolutely close a connection rather than just letting it get finalized. Are you trying to write your own connection pooling? If so, don't - the framework provides it automatically. Just create a new `SqlConnection` and it will take the underlying connection from a pool.

You should use a `using` statement to make sure the connection is disposed whatever happens:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = GetConnection(dbContext))
{
    MyComponent adapter = new MyComponent(connection);
    adapter.Update(_SqlTable);
}
```

You should document that `MyComponent` does *not* take responsibility for the lifetime of the connection in this case. An alternative would be to make `MyComponent` implement `IDisposable`, pass it the data context in the constructor, and dispose of that:

```
using (MyComponent adapter = new MyComponent(dbContext))
{
    adapter.Update(_SqlTable);
}
```

It's hard to give much further design advice without knowing what `MyComponent` does.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I am not using my own connection pool. It's default server pool. Unfortunately My component is an autogenerated dataset adapter that doesn't override System.ComponentModel.Component's Dispose(). So I have to dispose connection with "Using".